# Connect Magento with MSSQL

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mssql

I wanted to connect my magento store to MS SQL.I was searching online for this weather this is possible or not.

Here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html i saw that Magento Enterprise Edition will support Oracle or Percona as well but i am not sure whether Magento EE will support MS SQL.

If we can connect magento with MSSQL please let me know how can I achieve this

why I want this is I have one of my site in the .net and using mysql and I want to use that database.

Answer (score 3):

Magento uses the [Zend DB adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html) to connect to a database. I guess since that accepts MSSQL it should theoretically be possible but it will probably require you to make quite a lot of custom queries in Magento compatible with MSSQL syntax.

I would suggest using MySQL to prevent issues.

Comment: ok can u suggest on i can use mysql and when thr are orders or any customer registration will trigger into the mssql database

Comment: I guess you would have to write a migration script that queries to MySQL database and writes that into the MsSQL database, perhaps run it every 5 minutes or so